# php session variable controled by a link click

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo '<a href="/somepage.php">'.$row['somevalue'].'</a>';
}
```

Now, i need to open a `$_SESSION['somevalue']` depending on which link was clicked.

How could it be done ?

Comment: `$_SESSION['somevalue'] = $row['somevalue']`?

Comment: use session_start(); at starting of page and add $_SESSION['somevalue']=$row['somevalue'];  in while loop

Comment: @Usman that wont work, session will take the last value from loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a get parameter with the link:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo '<a href="/somepage.php?sessvalue='.$row['someothervalue'].'">'.$row['somevalue'].'</a>';
}
```

in somepage.php you can check the variable

```
if ($_GET['sessvalue'] == 'somevalue') {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Am asking for $_SESSION because i want to avoid pass it trough links

Comment: Then the only way I think is to use ajax when a link is clicked, send a variable which identifies the link, and fetch the value you want

Answer (score 0):

First, pass the required value to the page.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
<a href="/somepage.php?v=' . $row['somevalue'] . '">'.$row['somevalue'].'</a>';
}
```

On `sompage.php`

```
$val = $_GET['v'];
// now, open $_SESSION[$val];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Am asking for $_SESSION because i want to avoid pass it trough links

Comment: Oh ok...understood wrong. But, even you have to pass an identifier to the link which maps to the desired session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Then try dynamic name of Session variable i.e.

```
<?php
session_start();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo '<a href="/somepage.php">'.$row['somevalue'].'</a>';
$i++;
$_SESSION[$i]=$row['somevalue'];

}
?>
```

Hope it helps